# Multi-Dimensional Knapsack-Problem or Web application that shows if boxes fit into a bigger box (luggage)

Tags: luggage, online-resources, recommendations

I am looking for a web application that essentially can show if smaller boxes will fit into a bigger box (ideally also visualize it, give recommendations on effective placement of the boxes).

I need it because I'm flying back home and want to bring presents with myself to my close relatives' kids. My luggage size is 60cm x 43cm x 25cm. I have already ordered many presents online that will be shipped during the next week. The presents' package dimensions are as follows:

- 42cm x 36cm x 5cm
- 27cm x 27cm x 11cm
- 26cm x 12cm x 9cm
- 30cm x 20cm x 3cm
- 30cm x 8 x 8cm
- ... some 10 more packages...

Now, I am wondering if the small present boxes will fit into my luggage. If not, I can buy smaller presents or bigger luggage (the sum of 3 dimensions of my current luggage is 128cm, whereas the limit is 158cm) or find some other solution.

I feel like there needs to be such an online resourse (although I couldn't find it on google) and it seems too much work to use a raw 3D rendering software that won't give me recommendations on how to effectively place smaller items inside the luggage.

Comment: From working in a factory where I often have to package boxes and other items in big boxes, I'd say hands on, and careful working is the best way to solve. Often boxes are just not the size they should be, due to uneven filling.

Comment: These are Amazon dimensions, which are usually correct. Besides, the gifts are being shipped and will arrive only by the next Thursday, whereas my outbound flight is on Friday. I need to know in advance if the gifts will fit, so that I could change my orders or buy a bigger luggage.

Comment: The volume of one third of your presents (there are 10 more) is about one third of the volume of your box. You should calculate the total volume before beginning to pack. You also say "I have already ordered many presents online that will be shipped during the next week." Presumably they will be shipped to your house, for packing in the box, or you would not have mentioned them.

Comment: @WeatherVane, the first sentence of your answer was very helpful, thank you. But I didn't get the follow-up. Yes, I ordered 15 gifts and expect them to be delivered to my home, why? :)

Comment: "Santa Claus Problem"? Is that a name you invented yourself because your instance is about presents? This is an instance of wht is known as a (generalised) "knapsack problem".

Comment: @Henrik Yes. The OP can read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem to know more about the issue.

Comment: Dear Santa: a gentle reminder... please don't wrap my presents before you pack them in your sleigh; those TSA grinches won't like it. We've put out milk and cookies for you (and silly Daddy got a bottle of vodka).

Comment: Dear kiddos, don't worry, I won't ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve your immediate problem, use a [cubic volume calculator](https://www.matthewb.id.au/converter/cubic-volume-calculator.html). Granted, this is not 3D, but it will solve your problem of figuring out whether things will fit or not - as it works in volume, it doesn't matter the orientation.

*Commercial shippers use a CBM calculator which works the same way. CBM = Cubic Meter*.

You'll have to keep in mind the following restrictions though:

- Maximum size of luggage allowed (before its considered oversized or cargo)
- Maximum weight of each piece of luggage. This differs from airline, travel class, and route. Check with your airline.

Comment: Based on the terms you used in the answer, I found [3DBP](https://www.3dbinpacking.com/en/) with 1 month free trial. Although it is for companies, this was exactly what I needed (3D placement recommendation). So I just registered as a fictional company and used the service. Thus, I am accepting your answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's not just about volume, but fitment.  While it seems like an easily computerized problem, I am aware of large clothiers that still manually plan their cloth cuts.  The software *helps* the cut planner make the panels fit, but still the human factor is necessary for best efficiency. And they're only working in two dimensions!

So don't expect there to be a program on the app store to help you solve it in 3 dimensions.  It's a non-trivial problem.

Comment: But I already found one.

Comment: You may find limitations with the automated system.  The garment company did.